# Hide GridViewSummaryRowItem from radgridview vb.net winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

i have calculated sum of totals in radgridview and show the value in text box.which is done successfully .

```
    Dim summaryItem As New GridViewSummaryItem()
    summaryItem.Name = "ItemTotal"
    summaryItem.Aggregate = GridAggregateFunction.Sum

    Dim summaryRowItem As New GridViewSummaryRowItem()
    summaryRowItem.Add(summaryItem)
    RGV_SaleTransection.SummaryRowsBottom.Add(summaryRowItem)

    Private Sub RGV_SaleTransection_GroupSummaryEvaluate(sender As Object, e As  GroupSummaryEvaluationEventArgs) Handles RGV_SaleTransection.GroupSummaryEvaluate
    RTxt_SubTotal.Text = e.Value
    end sub
```

now i want to hide this summary row from grid.can anyone help
any other way will equally be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monisa,

You can hide the summary rows by using the following code snippet:

```
        For Each summaryRow As GridViewSummaryRowInfo In Me.RadGridView1.MasterView.SummaryRows
        summaryRow.MaxHeight = 1
    Next
```

I hope that it suits your scenario.

Comment: hi Dess Thanks , your code working 
i only have to change a line of my code 
RGV_SaleTransection.Mastertemplate.SummaryRowsBottom.Add(summaryRowItem)